# Django returns error 500 when DEBUG = False, ignores ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: django

I have django app which always returns error 500 page.
I have following code in settings.py:

```
import os
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError, e:
    pass
```

and local_settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

I have this on local machine, it always returns error code 500, no matter what I type in ALLOWED_HOSTS

Comment: Give the domain name you specify in `Site` object. `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.example.com']`

Comment: Can you check which is the error?

Comment: and if you change in `local_settings.py` the value of `DEBUG` to `True` it works without errors?

Comment: What is your domain? Django won't validate domain names with `_` in them for example

Comment: Damn I have the same problem, I'm getting mad... `ALLOWED_HOSTS` really has no effect on this. This happens with Django builtin development server as well, but including `'localhost'` or `'127.0.0.1'` in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, or even `'*'` has no effect at all.

Answer (score -1):

Django has ALLOWED_HOSTS = [] line right next to database config section. If you put your ALLOWED_HOSTS before this line your changes will be ignored. I guess this is a reason of your problem.